# Does google adsense ban sites which has links to mp3 files on other websites?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I wanted to build a website that will have the links to mp3s on other websites. Does google permit us to put the adsense on such website?

Comment: Why not? Do you mean copyright issues or similar things?

Comment: Do the other websites permit you to link to their content?

Answer (score 1):

Really depends what do you do with that (where the link goes).

In case you cant use Adsense, you could look into other adverts network where this is allowed.

http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1348688&topic=1271507&rd=1#Copyrighted_material

Comment: I just wanted to know that will google will ban my account on the complaint by other website or directly without intimating me

Comment: @Manish I think they have some automated program that helps them banning sites infringing their T&Cs. Adsense disapproved a site of mine with names of movies on it (although the sites I linked to are fully legal, and so is mine). I think it will be extremely similar for music

Answer (score 1):

It is no for Adsense. Any music/video downloads not allowed unless you're a very reputed company.